# Sublime Text, fullscreen at start

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

This is very simple question:

Is it possible to start Sublime Text in fullscreen mode in OSX?

I've already activated `"use_simple_full_screen":true` option.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this will help you out:

http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30078/is-it-possible-to-always-start-an-application-fullscreen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone also need this, I made a plugin to start Sublime Text in fullscreen mode. It is available with Package Control.
https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/AutomaticFullscreen

Comment: Doesn't work for me, see [#2](https://github.com/lefoy/AutomaticFullscreen/issues/2).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this isn't possible. I don't think I've seen any other program do this either, on OSX at least.